# "Couldn't Generate WSFilter" error in Policy Studio

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soa, policy

I am trying to register a WSDL in policy studio under location: 
Business Services > Web Service Repository > Web Service
but while registering I am getting this error:

> Couldn't Generate WSFilter

I also validated the WSDL through WS-i basic profile and the result was passed.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Here is the WSDL that I am trying to register:

```html
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Test_SOA_Service/Test_SOA_Service" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="Test_SOA_Service" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Test_SOA_Service/Test_SOA_Service">
<wsdl:documentation>
<abstractWSDL>
http://soadev1.cp.np.com:1234/soa-infra/services/Test_SOA_Service!1.0/Test_SOA_Service.wsdl
</abstractWSDL>
</wsdl:documentation>
<plnk:partnerLinkType name="Test_SOA_Service">
<plnk:role name="Test_SOA_ServiceProvider">
<plnk:portType name="client:Test_SOA_Service"/>
</plnk:role>
</plnk:partnerLinkType>
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Test_SOA_Service/Test_SOA_Service" schemaLocation="http://soadev1.cp.np.com:1234/soa-infra/services/Test_SOA_Service/test_soa_service_client_ep?XSD=xsd/Test_SOA_Service.xsd"/>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="Test_SOA_ServiceRequestMessage">
<wsdl:part name="payload" element="client:process"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Test_SOA_ServiceResponseMessage">
<wsdl:part name="payload" element="client:processResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="Test_SOA_Service">
<wsdl:operation name="process">
<wsdl:input message="client:Test_SOA_ServiceRequestMessage"/>
<wsdl:output message="client:Test_SOA_ServiceResponseMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="Test_SOA_ServiceBinding" type="client:Test_SOA_Service">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="process">
<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="process"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="test_soa_service_client_ep">
<wsdl:port name="Test_SOA_Service_pt" binding="client:Test_SOA_ServiceBinding">
<soap:address location="http://soadev1.cp.np.com:1234/soa-infra/services/Test_SOA_Service/test_soa_service_client_ep"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Vordel is configured in such a way that can hit only OSB services. Here i am trying to hit the BPEL service.